# Unable to enforce authentication requirement in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to enforce Authentication for access to my API, but the `permission_classes = permissions.IsAuthenticated,)` attribute of my `ViewSet` doesn't seem to be working. Because I try to access the User's profile later on when in `get_queryset()`, I'm getting errors like:

> TypeError: 'AnonymousUser' object is not iterable"

I also have authentication set in my rest_framework settings:

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
```

And I also added to my dispatch method before doing the other business logic checks on the User profile:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

That's not working either:

> File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 57, in rendered_content
>      assert renderer, ".accepted_renderer not set on Response"
>   AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response

Why do none of these authentication controls work?

Edit: here's a simplified version of `get_queryset()`:

```
kwargs = {} 
for k,v in self.request.query_params.items():
    if not validate_that_key_is_an_actual_model_field(k):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    kwargs[k] = v
return Product.objects.filter(fk_client=self.client)\
    .filter(**kwargs)\
    .order_by('uuid')\
    .select_related('fk_user')
```

Comment: Could you show your view?

Comment: It's several hundred lines; which part do you need?

Comment: At least your `get_queryset()` method, then?

Comment: I've added it, but I don't think you're on the right track. Authentication checks should take place before attempting to get the queryset.

Comment: Try to debug [this](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/d300c3c648e6141c47dd28769036727f85281721/rest_framework/views.py#L322) function. Do you have `IsAuthenticated` in `self.get_permissions()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was doing some other things in `dispatch()` that were executing before the super class's `dispatch` was called, and hence accessing the User profile before a Http401 could be returned by the super class. Additionally, because the super class's dispatch hadn't been called yet, the renderer hadn't been initialized properly (depending on the request's content headers) and so that was the source of the `AssertionError: accepted_renderer not set on Response`.